# How do I plot a convenient lognormal pdf with my data?

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, python

I have a random variable *Words per sentence* which contains those values:

```
words_per_sentence = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 22, 22, 22, 22, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 24, 24, 24, 24, 25, 25, 25, 26, 26, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 28, 28, 28, 29, 29, 29, 29, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 31, 31, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 34, 34, 34, 34, 34, 35, 35, 35, 36, 36, 36, 36, 36, 37, 38, 38, 39, 39, 40, 42, 42, 43, 43, 44, 45, 47, 48, 49, 49, 50, 50, 51, 52, 52, 54, 54, 55, 58, 62, 67, 67, 73, 80]
```

The observation space contains 500 values (*N=500*), and the mean and standard deviation are:

- *mu = 15.088*
- *sigma = 12.445*

I want to calculate a **three-parameters-lognormal PDF** for my variable and **plot it in a graph** but I do not get the result I want. This is my failing code up to now:

```
import math
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
data = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 22, 22, 22, 22, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 24, 24, 24, 24, 25, 25, 25, 26, 26, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 28, 28, 28, 29, 29, 29, 29, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 31, 31, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 34, 34, 34, 34, 34, 35, 35, 35, 36, 36, 36, 36, 36, 37, 38, 38, 39, 39, 40, 42, 42, 43, 43, 44, 45, 47, 48, 49, 49, 50, 50, 51, 52, 52, 54, 54, 55, 58, 62, 67, 67, 73, 80]
plt.hist(data, bins=50, color='c', alpha=0.75)
xmin = min(data)
xmax = max(data)
x = np.linspace(xmin, xmax, 200)
pdf = stats.lognorm.pdf(x, s=12.445, loc=1, scale=math.exp(15.088))
plt.plot(pdf, 'y')
```

The problem is that I do not get the PDF printed but a straight horizontal line in at the bottom of the graph. I cannot post any picture as I have not yet enough punctuation. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Your question seems to be how to plot
density curves on histograms of the normal and lognormal versions
of your data. If so, this is mostly a question
about the difference between (undocumented) Python
code and a program in R that may give what you want.

if you are confused about the relationship between lognormal and normal distributions, this is a
reasonable question here.

If this is a question about plotting density functions and histograms in R (or Python), then some users on this site may find your
question 'off topic', but here goes:

R code:

```
data = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
         3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
         3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 
         4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 
         5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 
         5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 
         6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 
         7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 
         8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 
         9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 
        10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 
        10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 
        11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 
        11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 12, 12, 12, 12, 
        12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 
        12, 12, 12, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 
        13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 
        14, 14, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 
        15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 
        16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 18, 
        18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 19, 19, 19, 
        19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 
        21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 22, 22, 22, 22, 23, 23, 23, 23, 
        23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 24, 24, 24, 24, 25, 25, 25, 26, 26, 
        27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 28, 28, 28, 29, 29, 29, 29, 30, 30, 30, 30, 
        30, 30, 31, 31, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 33, 33, 
        33, 33, 33, 33, 34, 34, 34, 34, 34, 35, 35, 35, 36, 36, 36, 36, 
        36, 37, 38, 38, 39, 39, 40, 42, 42, 43, 43, 44, 45, 47, 48, 49, 
        49, 50, 50, 51, 52, 52, 54, 54, 55, 58, 62, 67, 67, 73, 80)    # lognormal data

y = log(data)  # normal data
```

Now here is a histogram of the normal data along
with the density function of the normal curve with
mean and SD matching the sample mean and SD.

```
hist(y, prob=T, col="skyblue2")
curve(dnorm(x, mean(y), sd(y)), add=T, col="orange", lwd=2)
```

[image]

```
summary(y);  length(y);  sd(y)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  0.000   1.792   2.398   2.402   2.944   4.382 
[1] 500          # sample size
[1] 0.8255628    # sample SD
```

Finally, here is a histogram of your lognormal data along with the corresponding lognormal density
curve. Note that in R the parameters of a lognormal
distribution are the mean and SD of the corresponding normal distribution.

```
hist(data, prob=T, ylim=c(0,.07), col="skyblue2")
curve(dlnorm(x, mean(y), sd(y)), add=T, col="orange", lwd=3)

summary(data)
    Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
   1.00    6.00   11.00   15.09   19.00   80.00
```

[image]